# IntelliSense preventing semicolon input

Tags: visual-studio

For example if I want to type `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)` when I get to the `n` if I type a semicolon nothing will happen because of the intellisense auto completion.

So I have to press `;` twice which is pretty annoying. It also used to do this with `>>` but I managed to fix that problem and now it only blocks semicolons.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2019, from the `Tools` Menu Item, select `Options`.  Then navigate to the `Environment` node, and then to the `Keyboard` subnode.

Find the `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.QuickActionsForPosition` command.  You should see a `;` in the `Shortcuts for selected command:` combo box.  Click remove and change it back to `Ctrl+.` or to your desired IntelliSense keyboard shortcut.

Comment: What do you see when you type a semicolon into the "Press Shortcut Keys" text box on that same settings page?

Comment: I can't write anything in that text box for some reason that doesn't contain shift alt or ctrl